# OLED display 128x64 SSD1309 integrated with a TMS320F28377x via SPI-4 wires

Tags: c, oledb, microcontroller, texas-instruments

I am a beginner in programming and want to control an OLED display 128x64 (controller SSD1309 integrated) with a TMS320F28377x via SPI-4 wires. I found a library in the internet which is developed for STM. Would it also apply to my microcontroller? If so, what exactly has to be changed or edited? [LINK](https://github.com/feicccccccc/SSD1309OLED) to the Library

thank u

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. -- What happens if you try to use it with your microcontroller? (For sure you'll get some errors.) What did you try to solve the problems? -- Learning to program is about trying, making errors, reading documentation, changing the approach, and all over again.

Comment: All you need (apart from the hardware, obviously) is a working SPI driver and the initialization code. The trickiest part with these parts is always to get the initialization working, the manufacturer (Solomon) usually have examples. I'd recommend single stepping the code and watch the SPI data line with scope as you go.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write yourself low level functions like `GPIO_SetBits` or `SPIWrite(something);` for you platform - then yes, you will be able to port it.

If it is too difficult for you, or you do not understand what I am writing about, I rather recommend to start with "blinking LED" and a good C book.